# Método para salvar vários "Players" em uma lista

Tags: java

Eu quero fazer um sistema de *party*, o único comando será `/party PLAYER` (caso o *player* já esteja na *party*, ele será removido e caso ele não esteja, será adicionado).

Porém não achei uma forma de fazer isso, tentei com `HashMap` usando `<Player, String[]>` porém não daria para ir adicionando um novo *player* na *party* por ser um número determinado na `String[] string = {"Player1", "Player2", "Player3"}`.

Tentei com `ArrayList`, porém também não consegui, então gostaria de saber uma forma de consiguir fazer isso.

Comment: Por que não conseguiu com `ArrayList`?

Comment: Por que cada player que digitar `/party PLAYER` precisa de um `ArrayList` nova.

Comment: Edita a questão com o código que tu já tens, acho que interpretei mal a questão.

Comment: Mas assim, tu quer usar uma `"lista"` pra armazenar/adicionar/remover os **players**, certo?

Comment: Eu quero uma `String[] party` que possa usar `party.add(PLAYER);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu pode fazer isso com `ArrayList`, da seguinte forma:

```java
ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
//para adicionar
players.add("novo_registro");
//para remover
players.remove(novo_registro");
```

EDIT - para criar conforme tu disse no comentário:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> parties = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: Mas por exemplo a party do `player1` contem `(player2,player3)` e a party do `player5` contem `(player6,player7,player8)`, como eu faria isso ??

Answer (score 2):

Use um hashmap que salve o player principal(que criou a party) e como value salve uma arraylist do tipo `Player[]`

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Party {

    private final Set<String> players;

    public Party() {
        this.players = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    }

    public void toggle(String player) {
        if (players.contains(player)) {
            players.remove(player);
        } else {
            players.add(player);
        }
    }

    public String[] toArray() {
        return players.toArray(new String[players.size()]);
    }

    public Set<String> toSet() {
        return new LinkedHashSet<>(players);
    }
}
```

Aqui vai um exemplo/teste de como usar a classe `Party`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Party p = new Party();
        p.toggle("Pedro"); // Adiciona o Pedro
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(p.toArray())); // Imprime [Pedro]
        p.toggle("Maria"); // Adiciona a Maria
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(p.toArray())); // Imprime [Pedro, Maria]
        p.toggle("Pedro"); // Remove o Pedro
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(p.toArray())); // Imprime [Maria]
        p.toggle("Carlos"); // Adiciona o Carlos
        p.toggle("Fernando"); // Adiciona o Fernando
        System.out.println(p.toSet()); // Imprime [Maria, Carlos, Fernando]
        p.toggle("Carlos"); // Remove o Carlos
        System.out.println(p.toSet()); // Imprime [Maria, Fernando]
    }
}
```

[Veja rodando no ideone](http://ideone.com/qzVwzi)

Observe que você adiciona/remove os *players* com o método `toggle(String)`. Para obter a lista de *players* como um *array*. use o método `toArray()`. Se preferir trabalhar com a lista de *players* na forma de um `Set`, use o método `toSet()`. No teste, eu uso ambos a fim de mostrar como podem ser usados.

Modificar o *array* retornado pelo `toArray()` não vai interferir na `Party`, e alterar a `Party` não vai interferir nos *arrays* obtidos anteriormente através do `toArray()`. Da mesma forma, modificar o `Set` retornado pelo `toSet()` não interfere na `Party` e alterar a `Party` não interfere nos `Set`s obtidos anteriormente pelo `toSet()`. Isso garante que alterações na `Party` não causem efeitos colaterais imprevistos nos *arrays* e `Set`s obtidos anteriormente, e também garante que alterações nestes *arrays* e `Set`s não causem efeitos colaterais imprevistos na `Party`.

Além disso, deve-se notar que os *players* serão mantidos sempre na ordem em que foram inseridos. Isso ocorre porque estamos usando um `LinkedHashSet`. Se ao invés disso, fosse usado um `HashSet`, a ordem dos *players* seria aleatória. Se fosse usado um `TreeSet`, os *players* estariam automaticamente ordenados alfabeticamente.

Estou assumindo também que o `Party` será usado em uma única *thread*. Se este não for o caso, a forma mais simples de deixá-lo seguro para ser usado em múltiplas *threads* é colocar o modificador `synchronized` nos métodos `toggle(String)`, `toArray()` e `toSet()`.